# How to play bunch of h264 files from amazon as URL using ffmpeg in android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I have bunch of .h264 files in amazon s3. I can play each file by selecting them.  My challenge is to play more than one file at a time like below image through amazon s3 url without saving file in sd card. [image]